# How to objectively monitor REST APIs performance based on the request/response size

Tags: rest, performance, monitoring

We recently integrated a monitoring solution (Data Dog) for our REST-APIs based microservices. The monitoring solution gives us many useful metrics. For example, we can see the average response time for each API. It also alerts us if the average response time increases for a specified period etc. However, we recently started to look deeper into performance monitoring and we found the absolute response time does not always mean much. If the POST request contains big number of items to be inserted to DB or processed, the response time naturally increases. Similarly, if the GET request is expecting thousands of items to be returned, the resposne time is expected to be longer. What we are missing here, is a measurement of the response time in correlation to the response/request size. We did some research and we could not find any tool/library which could support that out-the-box.

I want to tap into people's experience here. What is the best way to have more objective performance monitoring setup? If response/request size is not the right direction, what should be the direction? We also considered implementing throttling on the response/requests (e.g. REST API rejects POST requests which contain more than x number of items,...etc), which will give more predictable performance. Are there other ways to go about this?

Our purpose is to offer more predictable response time for our APIs (SLAs/SLOs), and to be able to find out the cause of any performance issues when they happen.

Comment: The most common approach for large responses is to provide an API to page or iterate through the data.  That limits the size of any one request.  Similarly you can have a 413 payload too large if someone is requesting too many resources to be updated at once.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you need, and what you have available.

Using the example of Azure Log Analytics, the request/response sizes are logged alongside the performance:

[image]

Therefore, you could write a query to group your performance metric by those sizes, or to base your metric only on requests that fall within an acceptable size range.

While I don't have black-and-white proof of this, Azure's smart insights seems to be smart enough that it doesn't send out "fake" alerts for low performance when bulky requests are being fired.
I know this because we used to have an app with bulk data imports running between 12AM-3AM, the only slow requests we had, and Azure never once alerted me as if these imports were a slowed down version of the (much more performance) requests we'd be handling during office hours, but it *did* alert me to genuine slowdowns on our non-bulk requests. So it clearly "knew" to expect longer execution time on those bulk import requests.

Similarly, if your code manually logs its performance, you could create a separate performance log to which you only log when the request meets certain criteria (e.g. excessively large requests don't factor into performance), or use different logs depending on the size, or simply use the same log for everything but document the size so that you can filter on it in the future when monitoring those logs.

> It also alerts us if the average response time increases for a specified period etc.

As a third option, if you're only interested in specific increases in response time, you could target specific endpoints of your API which are always of a similar size and consistent performance, and extrapolate that if these endpoints are experiencing a spike in performance issues, that this most likely extends to the application at large.

This is more an educated guess than it is a given, but it can be a very reliable indicator if the endpoint consistently performs the same effort for each request, e.g. a heartbeat endpoint.

> We also considered implementing throttling on the response/requests (e.g. REST API rejects POST requests which contain more than x number of items,...etc), which will give more predictable performance. Are there other ways to go about this?

Refusing to handle a valid request that you could handle, purely so that it's easier for you to write a metric, is IMHO sacrificing user experience for developer experience, which is the wrong priority for a company.

There are valid reasons to cap the size of requests, but "we like a clean metric" isn't one of them.

However, like I mentioned before, there's nothing wrong with changing your logging based on the size of the incoming request. Whether it is excluding large requests from the performance log, documenting its size, tracking it as a separate metric, ... These are all options based on what you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks. May I know what is the measurement used for Azure here? Is it pure size in KB? If so, how would Azure know there could small request in KB but entails a lot of processing powers, unless Azure somehow parses and understands the request?

Comment: @Hawk: I think the point is more that based on the URL/route, Azure notices that certain requests take always consistently longer than others, and therefore understands that these requests take longer. As a simple example, if on a good day /api/A takes 200ms and api/B takes 2500ms, with some degree of consistency, then on another day /api/A taking 3000ms is sign of a problem, but /api/B taking 3000ms is not.